# Android 2.0 devices

Tags: android

I see the versions of Android 2.0 and 2.01 are obsolete.

And when im looking at the android fragemtation cakes 2.0 is not even listed, does this mean there are no more android 2.0 devices out there?

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Because that would mean I could target 2.1 as minimum target instead of 2.0, and would reach the same number of devices.

Is it really possible that there are no more devices with 2.0 and 2.01?

I googled but didnt find any informations about it.

Vino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) page, you notice that 2.0 isn't mentioned, so you shouldn't be worried about devices with android 2.0. Basically afaik 2.0 has been replaced by 2.1.

Comment: This means that if there are any 2.0 devices left on the market that haven't upgraded to 2.1 due to some vendor firmware preventing them, they will be so small market share that they don't even show up on the list any more, meaning they will be much less than 0.2% market share.